# How can I get the x, y, width and height parameters of the text inside the UILabel?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uikit, uilabel

I'm trying to use [RectangleCountour](https://github.com/mayoff/RectangleContour) library to make a rounded rectangles with rounded corners between lines behind all the text strings separately in UILabel. The parameters (x, y, width and height) are dynamic and i have to count it for every string. When I try to count it for every line and don't match with the text inside the label or set the rectangle for all the label based on the biggest width.
Here is an example of the code where I just set the random parameters:

```
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            if let customFont = customFont {
                font = customFont
            }

        let rects: [CGRect] = [
            CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 30, height: 40),
            CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 50, height: 60),
        ]
            let contour: IsoOrientedContour = rects.contour()
            let roundedPath: CGPath = contour.cgPath(cornerRadius: customCornerRadius ?? 6)
            let uiPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: roundedPath)

            guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

            context.setFillColor(customBackgroundColor?.cgColor ?? UIColor(red: 94/255, green: 17/255, blue: 82/255, alpha: 0.58).cgColor)

            context.addPath(roundedPath)
            context.closePath()
            context.fillPath()

            super.draw(rect)
        }
    }
```

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn8Qs.png)

And this is what I want [Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC0Vg.jpg)
Seems like I have to draw the rect for every string based on its parameters, but I don't know how to count them.
Or maybe you know the other libraries to implement this?

Comment: The code to do this is literally in [the demo app's code](https://github.com/mayoff/RectangleContour/blob/main/Sources/PhoneDemoAppModule/TextDemoView.swift).

Comment: Yes, but it is SwiftUI, im using UIKit and there are some mismatches

Comment: `UILabel` doesn't expose any text layout information. You need to compute it yourself. You might be better off just using a `UITextView` directly instead of a `UILabel`, and set `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` to make it non-editable.

Answer (score 2):

The [demo code](https://github.com/mayoff/RectangleContour/blob/main/Sources/PhoneDemoAppModule/TextDemoView.swift#L100) in RectangleContour shows how to do this with a `UITextView`.

> ```
> let range = NSRange(0 ..< layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs)
> let insets = textView.textContainerInset
> var usedRects: [CGRect] = []
> layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: range) { _, usedRect, _, _, _ in
>     var usedRect = usedRect
>     usedRect.origin.x += insets.left
>     usedRect.origin.y += insets.top
>     usedRects.append(usedRect)
> }
> send(.setRects(usedRects))
> ```

The idea is to use `NSLayoutManager.enumerateLineFragments` to get all the rects used by each line.

To do the same with a `UILabel`, you just need to create an `NSTextStorage` that contains the label's text, a `NSTextContainer` the same size as the label, and a `NSLayoutManager` that lays out the text. Then you can also use `NSLayoutManager.enumerateLineFragments`.

Example code:

```
// creating the label
let label = UILabel(frame: .init(x: 75, y: 75, width: 80, height: 200))
label.text = "This is what I expected to see"
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.textAlignment = .center
label.sizeToFit() // this is important
view.addSubview(label)

// creating the container, storage and layout manager
let storage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: label.bounds.size)
let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
storage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines

// as in the demo code
let range = NSRange(0 ..< layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs)
var usedRects: [CGRect] = []
layoutManager.ensureLayout(for: textContainer)
layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: range) { _, usedRect, _, r, _ in
    // add some padding if you want
    usedRects.append(usedRect/*.insetBy(dx: -2, dy: -2)*/)
}

// add the shape as another UIView behind the label for your desired result
let path = usedRects.contour().cgPath(cornerRadius: 10)
let backgroundView = UIView(frame: label.frame)
backgroundView.backgroundColor = .clear
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
shapeLayer.zPosition = -100
backgroundView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
view.addSubview(backgroundView)
view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundView)
```

[image]

Note that `sizeToFit` is important here because `UILabel`s centre their text vertically, but `NSTextContainer`s don't do that. `NSLayoutManager` would produce rects that are aligned to the top of the label.

Comment: Looks good to me. Possibly you should call the label's `textRect(forBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:)` method to get the offset where the label starts layout.